# How to ignore primary key when I insert room database entity

Tags: android, entity, android-room, primary-key, android-room-relation

How do I ignore the primary key when I insert some entity?

Room Entity has to have more than 1 primary key.
For example, there is an entity following under.

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["id"], tableName = "someEntity")
data class SomeEntity(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val someClass: SomeClass<*>? = null
)
```

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
abstract fun insert(obj: SomeClass): Completable
```

Parameter "obj" will have two column(fields).
When I have insert logic like that,
do I have to care about `id` (with autoGenerate annotation) column?

When I insert `SomeEntity` with dao,
I can only get `SomeClass<*>?` type, without `id: Int`.
Does `@AutoGenerate` annotation on column `id` can solve my problem?

Comment: I almost want to say yes but I am not sure what is your problem.

Comment: @TheLibrarian
when I have to insert `SomeEntity` with DAO, `SomeEntity` have two fields (id and someClass). But I can only get `SomeClass` property from server.
the insert logic will be like this.
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) {
   abstract fun insert(obj: SomeClass)
}
parameter "obj" will have two column(fields).
The problem that I think is when I have insert logic like that, do I have to care about "id"(with autoGenerate annotation) column?

Comment: Please ask 1 clear specific researched non-duplicate question. Debug questions require a [mre]. Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Room` understands `val id: Int = 0` if it is marked with @PrimaryKey as a value to be ignored when inserting.

```
@Entity
data class SomeEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    val someClass: SomeClass<*>? = null
)
```

and when creating a new instance `SomeEntity(someClassInstance)` is completely fine.

Note: if `SomeClass` isn't a basic class that SQL is able to save, you need to have some way to serialize it.